# Read from multiple databases in Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a project where I want to read from multiple databases using the same query and then insert the results in one database table.

My issue is that how I can pass multiple datasources to read from the DBs, so I have like 6 DBs + or - (DB2) I want to read from them and insert the result in postgres. If I have a table in the postgres database where it holds the database(s) credentials lie the drivers, url, username and password, can I read those DBs and put them in a list for example then pass this list to the reader (ex: `JpaPagingItemReader`) and the result will be passed to the writer to right in postgres?

Comment: Is there any order/relation between source tables and the target table? Are those tasks parallelisable?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but the target table is on a local instance of Postgresql and the source tables are the same in different DB2 datasources in different locations in which I want to collect the data from and insert in Postgresql, hope I replied correctly @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: By target table I mean the table you are writing to: `and then insert the results in one database table.`. In your case, if you those tasks are independent, you can create different steps (one for each table with its own reader) and run those steps in parallel.

Comment: did you get a solution for this issue @Elias Khattar